# Switch values of two rows in an SQL statement

Tags: mysql

How would I swap the operator_id between the two rows selected below?

i.e. the operator_id of `id=@job_offer_id` becomes the operator_id of `id=@job_received_id`, and vice versa.

```
query += "SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_offer_id;" +
         "SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_received_id";
```

I've included a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdc53/4

Comment: Could you please provide us input & output results of your issue

Comment: I've updated the question with a fiddle, hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try self join

```
update booking as o join booking as r
set o.operator_id = r.operator_id, r.operator_id = o.operator_id
where o.id = 2 and r.id = 3;
```

like this

Answer (score 1):

Try to save it on a variable and use it again to another query;

```
/* SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_offer_id; */
SELECT operator_id INTO @job_offer_id FROM booking WHERE id="2";
SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_offer_id ;

/* SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_received_id; */
SELECT operator_id INTO @job_received_id FROM booking WHERE id="3";
SELECT operator_id FROM booking WHERE id=@job_received_id ;
```